# Reusing VBA Array

Tags: arrays, vba

I would like to reuse vSheetNamesTemp array.
It's collecting sheets with q* but I want to use it for other sheets like w*.

[image: Please see image]

```
Sub main()
Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set swDrawing = swModel
Dim vSheetNamesTemp As Variant
vSheetNamesTemp = swDrawing.GetSheetNames
removed = 0        
For i = 0 To UBound(vSheetNamesTemp)
    vSheetNamesTemp(i - removed) = vSheetNamesTemp(i)
    SheetName = vSheetNamesTemp(i)              
    If Not SheetName Like "q*" Then
        removed = removed + 1
    End If
Next i
If (UBound(vSheetNamesTemp) - removed) >= 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve vSheetNamesTemp(0 To (UBound(vSheetNamesTemp) - removed))
    vSheetNames = vSheetNamesTemp
End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not post code pictures! Edit your question and post the code like it is (editable)...

Comment: What stops you from also putting `w*`s in the array?

Comment: You did not post your (editable) code... I do not want looking to your picture and write part of your code. So, move your array declaration at the module level. So, it should be used like it remained after removing your sheets. You  can even create a function to make the removal, having like parameters, the remained array and removal criteria. But why don't you remove the `w*` sheets in the same loop?

Comment: Sorry Guys I was struggling to put the code in there.  I still couldnt add the variable.

Comment: @FaneDuru I was thinking of a function but how would it add to the array?

Answer (score 0):

Try the next approach, please:

1. Create a variable on top of the module (declarations side):

   `Private vSheetNames As Variant`
2. Copy your transformed `Sub`:

   `Sub main()
    Dim arrCriteria As Variant, El As Variant
    'Please, appropriately declare the used variables. I do not use Solidworks`

   `Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swDrawing = swModel
    vSheetNames = swDrawing.GetSheetNames
    arrCriteria = Split("q*,w*,x*", ",") 'use here as many criteria you need`

   `For Each El In arrCriteria
       If UBound(vSheetNames) >= 0 Then
           removeSh vSheetNames, El
       End If
    Next
   End Sub`
3. In the same module, copy the next function:

   `Private Function removeSh(vSheetNamesTemp As Variant, strCriteria As String)
     Dim removed As Long, i As Long
      removed = 0
       For i = 0 To UBound(vSheetNamesTemp)
           vSheetNamesTemp(i - removed) = vSheetNamesTemp(i)
           If Not vSheetNamesTemp(i) Like strCriteria Then
               removed = removed + 1
           End If
       Next i
       If (UBound(vSheetNamesTemp) - removed) >= 0 Then
           ReDim Preserve vSheetNamesTemp(0 To (UBound(vSheetNamesTemp) - removed))
           vSheetNames = vSheetNamesTemp
       End If
   End Function`

The code is not tested, but it should work, I think. Please test it and send some feedback.